# Laravel Controller where('like') clause returning extra parameter

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I'm using Laravel Backpack's JSON select filter and when it returns a result, its adding and extra parameter:

```
public function albumsOptions() {
    $term = $this->request->input('term');
    $options = AlbumsModel::where('title', 'like', "%".$term."%")->get();
    return $options->pluck('title');
}
```

The parameters it returns are:

```
title:0 
title_text:Grey 2012 Cadillac CTS
```

But they're expected and needed to be:

```
title:Grey 2012 Cadillac CTS
```

Not sure where its getting the `title_text` parameter or why its passing the title to that instead of `title`.

Seems like it has to do with the `'like'` statement in the where clause because I have another filter that uses `'='` and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My error was in the in the categoryOptions functions

```
public function albumsOptions() {
    $term = $this->request->input('term');
    $options = AlbumsModel::where('title', 'like', "%".$term."%")->get();
    return $options->pluck('name');
}
```

I had the wrong `pluck()` parameters